# Javascript/jQuery timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I am making a chat, and I have a system that notifies the users when the other user is typing, all works good, however now I want to make it even better so it doesn't bug up, and to do this I need to sent an event through the server (Using websockets), so I want this not to fire every time a user presses a key, but send it each 4 seconds or so that the user is typing but I can't get what I've tried to work quite right, it seems to sort of work, but after a few seconds it's being fired every keypress, because the timer gets messed up or something.

```
var stillTyping = 0;

$("body").on("keypress",".chat-form .chat-textarea",function(event) {

if(!userTyping||stillTyping>3)
{
    friendID = $(this).attr("rel");
    var currentID = cookie("login");
    socket.emit('userChatTyping', friendID, currentID);


    setInterval(function(){stillTyping++},1000);
    stillTyping = 0;

}

clearTimeout(inputTimer);
userTyping = true;
inputTimer = setTimeout(finishedTyping, 1200);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set an interval here

```
    setInterval(function(){stillTyping++},1000);
```

so this function will get called every thousand seconds, regardless of whether the user stops typing.

You need to clear this interval when the user has stopped typing

```
var typeInterval=setInterval(function(){stillTyping++},1000);

if( $(".chat-textarea").val()==""){
   clearInterval(typeInterval);
   stillTyping=0;
}
```

You might want to use timeouts instead

```
var timeout=setTimeout(function(){stillTyping++},1000);


  if( $(".chat-textarea").val()==""){

 stillTyping=0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and also the counter, each time that fires, it counts faster and faster, instead of just each 1 second, I guess it would be multiple intervals going at the same time

Comment: Exactly.Every time there is a keypress, it adds another interval. So by the 100th keypress, you have 100 increments on still typing

Comment: Do you know of a way to stop this?

Comment: Set time outs instead of intervals